# Give response to JWT wrong Authentication Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have applied [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) and created one asp.net core web API authentication application.

Everything is fine and running perfect but if I pass the wrong authorization key it is not returning anything.

I tried below code to test but I am not getting context delegate.

```
x.Events.OnChallenge = context =>
                {
                    // Skip the default logic.
                    context.HandleResponse();

                    var payload = new JObject
                    {
                        ["error"] = context.Error,
                        ["error_description"] = context.ErrorDescription,
                        ["error_uri"] = context.ErrorUri
                    };

                    return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload.ToString());
                };
```

I also want to set custom error return code for the wrong authorization so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My configuration services code is :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })

            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            // configure DI for application services
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work since in startup.cs file you would have used

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
{//other stuff}
```

which works with [Authorize] data annotation on your methods and concurrently only when a valid token is passed.

Later you can extract claims and perform validation on

```
HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

You can check this...if it helps [link1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315274/get-claims-from-a-webapi-controller-jwt-token)

Comment: I didn't get your point. Where I have to make changes? I tried your code app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
{//other stuff} but it is not available. I only use those packages that is defined in the [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) I have given in my question.

Comment: Check this...if it helps [link] https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/   and [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315274/get-claims-from-a-webapi-controller-jwt-token