# Creating an API for external use

Tags: laravel, rest, api

I am using Laravel on my project. But am looking to create an API for other services/companies to use like showing some details. These calls need to be protected through some form of a token/secret like most other API's like payment providers or any others.

The problem I'm having and I don't think I am using the correct words is that when I look for help on this subject, it's all for a REST API for internal use, like when you build a mobile app or use a javascript frontend accessing this.

Is there a specific term I am missing or what is being misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Laravel passport service](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport)

Answer (score 0):

This is with regards to JWT token

You can check this...if it helps [link1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315274/get-claims-from-a-webapi-controller-jwt-token)

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel passport for authentication http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/ .

It's actually one of the best ways to authenticate API. It actually uses tokens. And if it on laravel 5.7 you can use laravel's official package **telescope**   for logging and debugging your APIs