# How to convert string claims to a List<string>

Tags: c#, jwt

I am getting back a JWT Token and I am using the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to decode it so I can do validation on the token. I am able to strip the claims up to this point:

```
"{\"Account Manager\":\"true\",\"Administrator\":\"true\",\"Agent\":\"true\"}"
```

What I want is a `List<string>` that looks like this:

```
"Account Manager"
"Administrator"
"Agent"
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Looks like a job for `Newtonsoft.JSON` `.DeserializeObject<T>()` (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_1.htm)

Comment: What language is the string written in? It appears to be JSON; is it?

Comment: Here's a hint: "JWT" is an acronym for "JSON Web Token".

Comment: @EricLippert Its originally a JWT token, When it gets Decoded it is a C# string, that looks like JSON

Comment: first thing I would do is to replace \" with "  then use NewtonsoftJSON to deserialize

Comment: Then I concur that using a JSON parser is the way to go.

Comment: @curiousBoy I'm like 99% sure that it's just the debug view and that the real string doesn't actually contain \.

Comment: @Robert - look at this post. It may help you to get what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546142/how-do-i-use-json-net-to-deserialize-into-nested-recursive-dictionary-and-list

Comment: How exactly are you decoding the token? I wouldn't expect you to need to manually parse JSON here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kirk has a good point, how are you decoding the token? It's a little strange to be dealing with the JSON string directly.  Normally you'd decode it into a `JwtSecurityToken` and access the `ClaimsPrincipal` and `Claims` under that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315274/get-claims-from-a-webapi-controller-jwt-token/50520437) for some info that may help).  Nevertheless, if you're determined to forge ahead, this is how I'd do it.

You have a bunch of key-value pairs, and I'm assuming you only want a list of the values where the claim value is `true`. I'd filter them as follows:

```
    string json = "{\"Account Manager\":\"true\",\"Administrator\":\"true\",\"Agent\":\"true\"}";

    var vals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
    var list = vals.Where(v => v.Value == "true").Select(v => v.Key);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like that: 
 `var claims = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(data);`